# Apply regular text to the same style

Tags: microsoft-word

I have MS Word document that contains sections marked as Heading2. Each section contains table and some text around it. How to apply the same font for whole text in document that is not Heading2 and table?

Comment: Your regular text should be the Normal style. Set Normal for the font you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the style of the text for which you would like to set
the font is Normal. Here is how to do that:

- In Word, click CTRL+H to enter the "Find and Replace" dialog
- Click inside the "Find what" field
- Click *More>>*
- Click *Format > Style...*
- Click *Normal* in the list and then OK
- Click in the "Replace with" field
- Click *Format > Font...*
- Find and click the new font in the "Font:" field and then click OK
- Back in the "Find and Replace" dialog, click "Replace All"
- The job is done.

I suggest to take a backup of your document before making such as
sweeping change. Check well and don't save if it has changed
too much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your document only consists of

- Paragraphs formatted as "Heading 2"
- Tables
- Text around tables that doesn't have a special style applied to it

And now you only want to change the 3rd point (text around tables that doesn't have a special style applied to it).

In that case, it's probably the easiest, that you change the font of the "Normal" style:

1. Do a right-click on the "Normal" style and select "Modify"
2. Choose a font that you like and save the settings with a click on "OK"
3. Optional: If this changed the font of your "Heading 2" style (and you don't like this change), do a right-click on the "Heading 2" style and revert the font change for that style)
4. Optional: If the change in step 2 changed the font of your table content, simply create a custom style for your table content and apply the style to the tables